# Assigning a value post while-loop results in error

Tags: f#

I'm struggling to figure out why I receive the following error:

> Block following this 'let' is unfinished. Expect an expression.

```
    let hashset = System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<int>()
    let mutable continueLooping = true

    while (continueLooping) do 
        let value = System.Random().Next(0, 12)
        let success = hashset.Add(value)
        continueLooping <- hashset.Count <> 12
    let z = hashet
```

The error is based on the following line:

```
let z = hashset
```

Why am I receiving this error?

NOTE:

I am new to F#. As a result, please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Is this part of a function definition? Are you trying to return `hashset`?

Comment: No. Not yet. I'm just trying to view the execution results in the Interactive Window.

Comment: In that case you should just be able to use `hashset` alone. A `let` expression would look like `let z = hashset in someExpression` which is why the compiler is complaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I can tell it's just because you mixed tabs and spaces in there - and in deed this works if I evaluate it in FSharpInteractive:

```
let hashset = System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<int>()
let mutable continueLooping = true

while (continueLooping) do 
   let value = System.Random().Next(0, 12)
   let success = hashset.Add(value)
   continueLooping <- hashset.Count <> 12

let z = hashset
```

evaluates to

```
val hashset : System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<int>
val mutable continueLooping : bool = false
val z : System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<int>
```

then `z |> Seq.toArray` evaluates to

```
val it : int [] = [|2; 8; 9; 3; 4; 10; 5; 11; 0; 6; 1; 7|]
```

which seems fine

---

btw: as you have a slight typo in there: `... z = hashet` instead of `hashset`I think you did not copy&paste the code that caused your error anyways.

Comment: Thanks Carsten. By-the-way, would this be an ideal method to generate random numbers? I guess I can post this question on a separate thread... After all, I really do want to learn this language.

Comment: well no you would not do it in a loop and you would probably not recreate a `Random` instance (your `System.Random() ...`) all the time - but yes open another question